# Where put this common code?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have these lines at many places.

```
<% if(controller.action_name == 'sort_data') %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    changePaginationToPost("pagin-block","orderfrm")
  });
</script>
<% end %>
```

In which file i have to put this code ? And how to call that file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep it in the sort_data view page without if condition.
If you are using this in more than one view pages then make a partial and include it in your view pages.

Comment: How can i include it in view pages ? render :partial => "/shared/sort_data"

Comment: Is there any other way to include it ?